# Starting Python VEnv in .cmd file on Windows

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, virtual-environment

In a nutshell: I want to start a Python (GUI) app in a venv on windows by double-clicking on a start.cmd file.   Everything now works, except: I can't get the CMD terminal window disconnected  (running in a separate process) from the Python application.

i.e., the CMD window does everything as expected, but then doesn't close.  When I close the CMD window manually, it kills the python app.    I thought the command `START /B ""` was supposed to be the same as `app &` on linux/mac, but apparently not.

As a simplified example, create and save this simple hello_world.py to emulate:

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
a = Label(root, text="Hello World")
a.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Then copy the below into a Start.cmd file and double-click.  With this simple setup, i get the behavior: CMD doesn't close, and if i manually terminate the python gui dies too (i.e., running as subprocess, not independent).

```
cd /D "%~dp0"

echo Setup Python Virtual Environment
echo (this might take a minute the first time)
python -m venv ./env

echo Start Application...  success is being able to close CMD window, and have hello_world survive.
START /b "" .\env\Scripts\activate &&hello_world.py
```

I solved this on the Mac/linux versions in 3 seconds with one character: &
After several hours, Windows is just not working.

Appreciate any thought... thanks!

Comment: Not the same but related: This is hacky and may not work for your case, but I've had some luck with this script: https://github.com/gbuktenica/PsRun

Comment: Thanks - I have to distribute this to several hundred internal users, so I was aiming for plain-vanilla windows as possible.   i.e., not for me (i run on mac) but for other, non-technical users.  Their use-case has to be:  double-click something.

Comment: You don't actually need that whole repo. The script itself is pretty simple. That said, it does feel hacky: https://github.com/gbuktenica/PsRun/blob/master/PsRun.vbs

Comment: Thanks @xdhmoore - i tried out the script you pointed to - as promised it hid the terminal window, but I never saw python pop-up in my task manager as expected... i.e., something failed in handoffs between CMD / VBS / Py.  I really don't care if the terminal window appears, i just want a different process for the Python environment so the terminal window will close (or can be closed) after the app starts.  
On the positive side, you bring up a good point - i could dust off the ol' vbs skills (some 10 years rusty) and take a different approach.